# New site, same host, different port, doesn't respond

Tags: iis, iis-10

Windows Server 2019, IIS 10: I have created a second web site in addition to the default site, and so far a simple HTML file is the only content, for testing. I bound HTTP to port 8080 and HTTPS to port 8043, and did not enter host names for either site. HTTPS on the new site is bound to the same TLS certificate as the default site. The default site (let's call it **https://my.example.com**) still works as it always has, but both **http://my.example.com:8080** and **https://my.example.com:8043** simply time out when I make a request. There is nothing in the access log nor in the Windows event log showing that the request was received or that there was any error. The HTTP behavior is the same when I do not have any binding for HTTPS on the new site.

I have verified that the firewall is allowing inbound traffic on these ports. Evidently there's more to this than I know about - can someone please point me to what it is?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. You might have opened one firewall, make sure there isn't another one between you and the host.

Comment: "when I make a request", but from where? On the same machine or from another machine? Tools like Wireshark can easily tell if the packets actually land on the machine or not.

Comment: Form either the same machine or another, but in the end I just created a new DNS CNAME and associated the new site with that.